# How do I prevent my .png images being compressed in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

- I set the pixel format to RGBA8888:

  ```
  [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
  ```
- In the xcode build settings, I set "Compress PNG Files" to "No"
- My images are exported in photoshop as png-24.
- I'm running in the simulator.

And my images png images are still being compressed! Any idea's how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! It seems as though it will always compress your images on the simulator.

This doesn't happen when I build to my device.